# VBA: Excel Automation using VBA

Tags: excel, vba, automation, rpa

I have written multiple scripts in VBA for multiple Buttons in an excel sheet to automate a process for the same. All I want is for someone to review my code and critic its cleanliness. It would be very helpful to have suggestions on how to make the code cleaner and optimize the process.

```
Private Sub CommandButton1_Click()
 Dim last_row As Double
    Call ModelwithEach
    last_row = Range("F" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
    Range("AM1").Value = "WithEach"
     Range("AM3:AM" & last_row).Formula = "=F3&R3"
     Range("L3:L" & last_row).Formula = "=VLOOKUP(AM3,'[Indemed Datafeed Latest.xlsm]Sheet1'!$A:$B,2,0)"
     Range("M3:M" & last_row).Formula = "=VLOOKUP(AM3,'[Indemed Datafeed Latest.xlsm]Sheet1'!$A:$K,11,0)"
     Range("N3:N" & last_row).Formula = "=VLOOKUP(AM3,'[Indemed Datafeed Latest.xlsm]Sheet1'!$A:$H,8,0)"
     Cells.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeFormulas, xlErrors).Clear
     
End Sub

Private Sub CommandButton2_Click()
  Dim last_row As Double
 last_row = Range("U" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
 Range("V3:V" & last_row).Formula = "=VLOOKUP(U3,'[current pricing sheet july 2019 - Copy.xlsx]Sheet1'!$A:$B,2,0)"
 Range("W3:W" & last_row).Formula = "=VLOOKUP(U3,'[current pricing sheet july 2019 - Copy.xlsx]Sheet1'!$A:$B,2,0)"

 Dim Shipping As Double
    Dim i As Double
    Shipping = Range("W" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
    For i = 3 To Shipping
        If Range("W" & i).Value >= 70 Then
            Range("X" & i).Value = "Free Shipping"
            Range("Y" & i).Value = 0
            Range("Z" & i).Value = "Yes"
        ElseIf Range("W" & i).Value <= 69.99 Then
            Range("X" & i).Value = "Really Flat"
            Range("Y" & i).Value = 6.99
            Range("Z" & i).Value = "No"
        Else
        End If
        Next i
     


End Sub

Private Sub CommandButton3_Click()
Dim last_row As Double
Dim i As Double
last_row = Range("F" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
    For i = 3 To last_row
        If Range("N" & i).Value > Range("K" & i).Value Then
            Range("G" & i).Value = "McKesson"
        ElseIf Range("K" & i).Value > Range("N" & i).Value Then
            Range("G" & i).Value = "Independence Medical"
        End If
        Next i

    Range("XFD2:XFD" & last_row).Formula = "=UPPER(LEFT(Q2,2))"
    Range("S3:S" & last_row).Formula = "=PROPER(VLOOKUP(F3,'MediUSA wound Care Feed.csv'!$A:$G,7,0))"
    
    For i = 2 To last_row
        Range("T" & i).Value = Range("R" & i) & "/" & Range("S" & i)
    Next i
    
    
'If Range("M2:M" & last_row).Value = "Case" Then
'    Range("B2:B" & last_row).Formula = "=UPPER(LEFT(Q2,2))&F2"
'    Range("B2:B" & last_row).Value = Range("B" & i).Value & "-CS"
'ElseIf Range("M" & i) = "Box" Then
'    Range("B2:B" & last_row).Formula = "=UPPER(LEFT(Q2,2))&F2"
'    Range("B" & i).Value = Range("B" & i).Value & "-BX"
'   End If
'   Next i
For i = 2 To last_row
  If Range("F" & i).Value = Range("F" & i).Value And Range("S" & i) = "Case" Then
            Range("B" & i).Value = Range("XFD" & i) & Range("F" & i) & "-CS"
        ElseIf Range("F" & i).Value = Range("F" & i).Value And Range("S" & i) = "Each" Then
            Range("B" & i).Value = Range("XFD" & i) & Range("F" & i) & ""
        ElseIf Range("F" & i).Value = Range("F" & i).Value And Range("S" & i) = "Box" Then
            Range("B" & i).Value = Range("XFD" & i) & Range("F" & i) & "-BX"
        ElseIf Range("F" & i).Value = Range("F" & i).Value And Range("S" & i) = "Pair" Then
            Range("B" & i).Value = Range("XFD" & i) & Range("F" & i) & "-PR"
        ElseIf Range("F" & i).Value = Range("F" & i).Value And Range("S" & i) = "Package" Then
            Range("B" & i).Value = Range("XFD" & i) & Range("F" & i) & "-PK"
        ElseIf Range("F" & i).Value = Range("F" & i).Value And Range("S" & i) = "Carton" Then
            Range("B" & i).Value = Range("XFD" & i) & Range("F" & i) & "-CT"
        ElseIf Range("F" & i).Value = Range("F" & i).Value And Range("S" & i) = "Dozen" Then
            Range("B" & i).Value = Range("XFD" & i) & Range("F" & i) & "-DZ"
        ElseIf Range("F" & i).Value = Range("F" & i).Value And Range("S" & i) = "Vial" Then
            Range("B" & i).Value = Range("XFD" & i) & Range("F" & i) & "-VL"
        ElseIf Range("F" & i).Value = Range("F" & i).Value And Range("S" & i) = "Roll" Then
            Range("B" & i).Value = Range("XFD" & i) & Range("F" & i) & "-RL"
        ElseIf Range("F" & i).Value = Range("F" & i).Value And Range("S" & i) = "Tray" Then
            Range("B" & i).Value = Range("XFD" & i) & Range("F" & i) & "-TR"
        ElseIf Range("F" & i).Value = Range("F" & i).Value And Range("S" & i) = "Can" Then
            Range("B" & i).Value = Range("XFD" & i) & Range("F" & i) & "-CN"
        ElseIf Range("F" & i).Value = Range("F" & i).Value And Range("S" & i) = "Jar" Then
            Range("B" & i).Value = Range("XFD" & i) & Range("F" & i) & "-JR"
        ElseIf Range("F" & i).Value = Range("F" & i).Value And Range("S" & i) = "Bag" Then
            Range("B" & i).Value = Range("XFD" & i) & Range("F" & i) & "-BG"
        ElseIf Range("F" & i).Value = Range("F" & i).Value And Range("S" & i) = "Gallon" Then
            Range("B" & i).Value = Range("XFD" & i) & Range("F" & i) & "-GL"
        ElseIf Range("F" & i).Value = Range("F" & i).Value And Range("S" & i) = "Set" Then
            Range("B" & i).Value = Range("XFD" & i) & Range("F" & i) & "-ST"
        ElseIf Range("F" & i).Value = Range("F" & i).Value And Range("S" & i) = "Kit" Then
            Range("B" & i).Value = Range("XFD" & i) & Range("F" & i) & "-KT"
        ElseIf Range("F" & i).Value = Range("F" & i).Value And Range("S" & i) = "Gross" Then
            Range("B" & i).Value = Range("XFD" & i) & Range("F" & i) & "-GR"
        ElseIf Range("F" & i).Value = Range("F" & i).Value And Range("S" & i) = "Pad" Then
            Range("B" & i).Value = Range("XFD" & i) & Range("F" & i) & "-PD"
        ElseIf Range("F" & i).Value = Range("F" & i).Value And Range("S" & i) = "Tube" Then
            Range("B" & i).Value = Range("XFD" & i) & Range("F" & i) & "-TU"
        ElseIf Range("F" & i).Value = Range("F" & i).Value And Range("S" & i) = "Sleeve" Then
            Range("B" & i).Value = Range("XFD" & i) & Range("F" & i) & "-SL"
        Else
            Range("B" & i).Value = ""
        End If
        Next i
        
End Sub

Private Sub CommandButton4_Click()
Dim last_row As Double
Dim i As Double
last_row = Range("F" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
    For i = 2 To last_row
              If InStr(1, UCase(Range("B" & i)), "-MI") <> 0 Then
                Range("F" & i).Value = Range("F" & i + 1)
                Range("G" & i).Value = Range("G" & i + 1)
                Range("U" & i).Value = Range("U" & i + 1)
                Range("V" & i).Value = Range("V" & i + 1)
                Range("W" & i).Value = Range("W" & i + 1)
                Range("X" & i).Value = Range("X" & i + 1)
                Range("Y" & i).Value = Range("Y" & i + 1)
                Range("Z" & i).Value = Range("Z" & i + 1)
                Range("D" & i).Value = "Parent Matrix Item"
                Range("A" & i & ":AL" & i).Interior.Color = vbYellow
                Range("A" & i - 1 & ":AL" & i - 1).Value = Range("A1:AL1").Value
                Range("A" & i - 1 & ":AL" & i - 1).Interior.Color = vbGreen
                Range("AE" & i).Value = "<p>Warranty and stuff</p>"
                Range("AF" & i).Value = "<p>Return Policy</p>"
                Range("AA" & i).Value = Range("C" & i) & "|" & Range("F" & i)
                Range("Q" & i).Value = Range("Q" & i + 1)
                Range("E" & i + 1 & ":E" & last_row).Value = Range("A" & i)
                Range("E" & i).Value = " "
                
                
            Else
            Range("D" & i).Value = "Child Matrix Item"
          
        End If
        Next i
        Range("AG2:AG" & last_row).Formula = "Supply Item"
 
            
End Sub

Private Sub CommandButton5_Click()
Cells.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeFormulas, xlErrors).Clear
End Sub

Private Sub CommandButton6_Click()
     Dim last_row As Double
     last_row = Range("F" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
     Range("H3:H" & last_row).Formula = "=VLOOKUP(AM3,'[Mck Merge Sheet.xlsx]Sheet1'!$A:$D,4,0)"
     Range("J3:J" & last_row).Formula = "=VLOOKUP(AM3,'[Mck Merge Sheet.xlsx]Sheet1'!$A:$H,8,0)"
     Range("K3:K" & last_row).Formula = "=VLOOKUP(AM3,'[Mck Merge Sheet.xlsx]Sheet1'!$A:$J,10,0)"
     Cells.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeFormulas, xlErrors).Clear
End Sub
```

Any word of advice will be much appreciated and thanked for.

Comment: What's the purpose of this test: `If Range("F" & i).Value = Range("F" & i).Value` ?  That whole If block looks like a great candidate for `Select Case` or a lookup table on a worksheet.  All `Range()` and `Cells()` should have a qualifying worksheet object.

Comment: ...even though this is in a worksheet module, where the default sheet would be the sheet the module is attached to.  In this case you can use `Me` to refer to the sheet

Comment: Is there an other way to check if a cell has some value "If Range("F" & i).Value = Range("F" & i).Value"